# Make image accessible from other ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I just want to know the code for making an image called **profpic** accessible to all other ViewControllers that I make or intend to make. I have read many posts on global variables, public variables, and other suggestions that have yet to work. If it helps, I am specifically using this to display an image from **ViewControllerA** as the background for **ViewControllerB**.

Comment: [Passing data between view controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5210535/643383)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton class and put the `UIImage` on it. Set it in `ViewControllerA` and get it in `ViewControllerB`

```
@interface MySingleton : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *myImage;

+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance;

@end


@implementation MySingleton

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (MySingleton *)sharedInstance {
    static MySingleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

To access `myImage`

```
// set myImage in ViewControllerA
MySingleton *mySingleton = [MySingleton sharedInstance];
mySingleton.myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];

// get my image in ViewControllerB
MySingleton *mySingleton = [MySingleton sharedInstance];
myImageView.image = mySingleton.myImage;
```

Comment: **That's not a singleton,** it's just a class that provides access to a shared object. A singleton is a class that can only be instantiated once.

Comment: im just still so confused why this is so difficult. this should be so simple lol i wish i knew how!! haha