# Make Image Global for all classes in xcode

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, global-variables

So I have created a jpeg file using the Facebook graph url with a user id in **ViewControllerA**. This image is saved as **profilePicture**. My question is how do I make this image (UIImage) global?

In other words, I just want to make this image available to any ViewController or other type of class that I make, outside from **ViewControllerA**. I am not sure if making it global or public will be more appropriate, I just need the best way to make it accessible from any controller. thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960053/make-image-accessible-from-other-viewcontroller/30960205#30960205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
ViewControllerB *vcb = segue.destinationViewController;
vcb.Bpic = profPicture;
}
```

Set up a

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain)  UIImage *pic;
```

in ViewControllerA. Set up a property like this in B and then set the background as profPicture.

This is a simple way to have it go from 1 VC to another. Apply this to where ever you need. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a property in AppDelegate class

**In Objective C :**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@property(nonatomic,strong)UIImage *yourImage;
```

And Access it Like

```
[(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] yourImage]
```

**In Swift >=1.2:**

```
import UIKit
var UIImage *yourImage

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

appDelegate.yourImage
```

**In Swift < 1.2**

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
appDelegate.yourImage
```